# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException is being thrown

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am watching a Laracast on forms, and my code is quite basic, and yet so is my knowledge of the framework. My code is below, and what your looking at, if you haven't taken a guess, is that I wish to create a list of values to be stored in a database, and to "Redirect" the user to there newly stored values. The "store" part seems to be the area of issue. Whenever I click "add food items" I am not redirected, yet this error appears, MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

```php
Route::get('food/create', 'FoodController@create');
Route::post('fond/post', 'FoodController@store');
Route::get('food/{id}', 'FoodController@index');
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Food;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FoodController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        $food = Food::find($id);

        return view('index')->with('food', $food);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('vendor.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = Request::all();
        $food = Food::create($input);

        return redirect('food/'.$food->id);
    }
}
```

```php
@extends('app')
@section('body')

<h1>Foods!</h1>
<h2>{{ $food->vegetables }}</h2>
<h2>{{ $food->fruit }}</h2>
<h2>{{ $food->grains }}</h2>
<h2>{{ $food->meat }}</h2>
<h2>{{ $food->sugar }}</h2>

@stop('body')
```

```php
@extends('app')
@section('body')

    {!! Form::open(['url'=>'food/store']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('vegetables', 'Vegetable item:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('vegetables', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('fruit', 'Fruit item:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('fruit', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('meat', 'Meat item:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('meat', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('grains', 'Grain item:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('grains', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('sugar', 'Sugar item:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('sugar', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div>          
        {!! Form::submit('Add Food items', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>

@stop('body')
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ROute::post('fond/post', 'FoodController@store');` be `Route::post('food/post', 'FoodController@store');`?

Comment: I just fixed the 0 in route and the food/store to food/post and the silly fond to food. It seems another error has appeared.  Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context    @MarkDavidson

Comment: @SethWarner `Request->all();` should be `$request->all();`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `get` method in you form opening tag. It should look like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'food/store','method'=>'get']) !!}
```